# Go : go get $GOPATH error, when GOPATH is set

Tags: macos, go, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

When running the go get command :

```
sudo go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

I get the following error

> package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: cannot download, $GOPATH not
>   set.  For more details see: go help gopath

**However $GOPATH is already set.**

Running `echo $GOPATH`  gives `/Users/userxyz/Desktop/Code`

Running `go env` gives

```
.....

GOPATH="/Users/userxyz/Desktop/Code"

...

GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

.....
```

I have already tried setting GOPATH as an environment variable by adding the following lines

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/Desktop/Code"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

to the following files, alternatively

```
~/.profile (/etc/profile)
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

This runs `go get` under `root` user, which does not have `$GOPATH` set.

Just do:

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

Generally, do:

```
go get
```

in the project folder, and it will install all dependencies. The following will install dependencies mentioned in tests:

```
go get -t
```

Comment: I have a doubt, wouldn't setting GOPATH in /etc/profile, set GOPATH for all users ?

Comment: What does `sudo env | grep GO` print? Anyway, why would you need to use `sudo go`?

Comment: I don't need to use sudo, I was just wondering since my understanding is that `/etc/profile` updates `GOPATH` system wide, and `sudo env | grep GO` returns nothing.

Comment: I am not a Unix guru, but maybe you need to restart? [See also](http://askubuntu.com/a/438170/7064)

Comment: I already tried restarting, and the link was helpful, Thank You

Comment: This problem persists even without sudo.

Comment: @Tyguy7 have you added the variables to `~/.profile`?

Comment: I'm not sure what my issue was, but when I started a new terminal window it was solved, and didn't come back.  Somehow my open session would set env vars but would not set GO env vars.

Comment: I got `permission denied` without sudo

Comment: @warvariuc "This package implements ICMP ping using both raw socket and UDP. If your program uses this package in raw socket mode, it needs to be run as a root user." https://github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping

Answer (score 3):

You just need to drop the `sudo`.
Your environment variables are defined at the user level. if you do `sudo go env` you'll see that `GOPATH` is not set there

Comment: This problem persists even without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sudo. If the "Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges" stops you, just re-open Xcode and accept the license agreement of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

*Just realized after writing the response that it's almost 4 years too late but I'll leave it up just in case there are others who might need the answers...*

So it seems like you might have created the directory with sudo or with root privileges. If you try `$go get` with a regular user you get a permissions error and when you try it with sudo you get a GOPATH unset error. I've had this problem recently, and I solved it by simply changing the ownership of the directory.

```
export GOPATH=/directory/of/your/goproject
chown -R ubuntu@staff $GOPATH
cd $GOPATH && go get
```

Here's just so you have some env variables to double check with:

```
export GOPATH=/home/ubuntu/work export
PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Keep in mind that there shouldn't be a need for you to declare or change $GOROOT.

---

Finally, you might want to use [profile.d][1] to export env variables:

```
cat > /etc/profile.d/setgoenv.sh <<EOL
export GOPATH=/home/ubuntu/work
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
EOL
```

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had imported an incorrect `GOPATH` that did not exist and an incorrect `GOROOT` in my `PATH`

setting my `export GOROOT=/opt/go` then `export GOPATH=$HOME/work`, ensuring `$HOME/work` existed and had access for my user seems to have solved the problem for `go get {whattoget}`, then ensuring `export GOPATH=$HOME/work
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin` was in my `~/.profile` helped. Nothing in this thread seemed to quite fit.

Going forward I might just start using Docker to build my go projects, as it's a bit of a pain, and the documentation and errors are lengthy but don't seem to explain what is wrong in any meaningful and clear way (`GOROOT` and `GOPATH` were both setup, but `PATH` `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` all seemed to be a little off).